# error Failed at the Project@0.0.0 ng-high-memory script I got stuck to create build due to this issue, Why i am getting this error?

Tags: angular, npm, build, angular8

[image]

Already ran these commands but did not meet the result

**ng build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer**

**npm cache clean**

**npm cache clean -- force**

**ng update @angular/cli@^8 @angular/core@^8**

**Deleted package-lock.json and run npm install**

**npm run ng-high-memory** -- getting error while running this command for increasing memory, I already increase error and warring memory manually also. Help me find out a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try this command using the `cmd` in the same directory.

Because some time the Powershell doesn't run the ng commands and npm commands properly

You can change the default terminal to the Command Prompt by pressing this Keys `Ctrl + Shift + P` then type in Select Default Terminal.
 You will get two to three options then select the **Command Prompt**

You can also select the default command prompt from the drop down available in the terminal

After the selection open a new terminal and try your commands

Comment: Thanks Hitesh, project successfully build now, I tried 2- 3 more command there to resolved further issue related to build and then got a success build. Thanks for your instant reply.